# The Formula of Sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that

$n.(n-1).2^{n-1}= \sum_{i=0}^n (n;i). i(i-1)$.

I tried like this way :

$\sum_{i=0}^n (n;i). i(i-1)= 0+0+ (n;2)2.1+ (n;3)3.2+...$. We know that $(n;0)+...+(n;n) =2^n$ from the properties of combination. But I do not show that.

Thanks your help.

Comment: What is $(n;i)$?

Comment: I figured that $(n;i)=\binom{n}{i}$, but then the equality does not hold for $n=2$ so either this is not true or $(n;i)$ is a completely different thing.

Comment: Yes, you right. (n;i) is the combination of n and i.

Answer (score 1):

Let$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i=(1+x)^n$.

$f'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}ix^{i-1}=n(1+x)^{n-1}$

$f''(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i(i-1)x^{i-2}=n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2}$

$f''(1)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i(i-1)=n(n-1)2^{n-2}$

Note the error in your statement.